# Android in app purchase this or that way?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I found two ways on the google pages to do in app billing

1. http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html
2. http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

both seem to follow different approaches, so the main question is what approach to follow?

For number 1 it seems that I have to provide a key to make a connection for security reasons, for 2 that doesn't seem to be the case. Furthermore for no. 1 I need to copy all kind of sample code into my project, it seems that for no. 2 that is not necessary. Any comments or insights?

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 provides you with a Helper class(IABHelper) that has functions for tasks like setting up a Service Connection with GP client, Querying items and Purchasing. You can use these functions to implement the IAB like using off-the-shelf APIs, which will save you time.

Method 2 will require all the tasks like Billing Service Connection Setup, Querying the Cache/Inventory and  carrying out the purchase all by yourself. However this will allow you customize the implementation to best fit your application design. When you do this, it is best if you adhere to the security/implementation guidelines followed in the Sample code.

It is up to you to decide between the two.

You will find that both of these approaches are essentially the same, if you dig enough into the code.

```
For number 1 it seems that I have to provide a key
```

You would have to specify a public key as a security measure in your in-app billing implementation either way.